# XML Viewer Web Part: XML feed requires username and password. How to pass credentials?

Tags: web-part, xml-viewer-web-part

I am getting the following error message:

"Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the XML Link property.  For more assistance, contact your site administrator."

I have an xml feed that prompts a windows security dialog.  I know the UN and PW, but I'm not sure how to implement this in XML.  Any ideas?

Thanks!
Flip